# Connect to Raspberry Pi Using Android Phone as Wireless Card

Tags: networking, android

I want to connect to my Pi from a remote device using the wireless hotspot provided by my Android phone. Below is the network configuration:

Pi<->192.168.42.112<->192.168.42.129<->Phone<->192.168.43.1<->192.168.43.x<->PC

1. 192.168.42.112 (usb0 on Pi)
2. 192.168.42.129 (rndis0 on phone)
3. 192.168.43.1   (wlan0 on phone)
4. 192.168.43.x   (wlan0 on PC)

My Pi is connected to my phone using USB tethering. I can ping from Pi to 192.168.43.1 (wlan0 interface on phone). I can also ping from PC to 192.168.42.129 (rndis0 interface on phone). The phone can talk to both the Pi and PC, but my Pi and PC can't talk to each other. How do I solve this problem? (My phone is rooted so any solution that requires root privileges is okay.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just found out that Android has IP Forwarding disabled by default.
To enable it, type the following:

`sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

The above will enable IP Forwarding, but still more needs to be done:

```
iptables -F -t filter      #Deletes all previous rules in filter table
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT #Allows IP forwarding
```

Now, I don't know if it's a good idea to delete the previous rules or if it's even required, but the good news is that these rules are not persistent. The next time you boot your Android device, the rules are reverted back to where they were. This also means you'll have to repeat this every time you boot the device.